# Why is my RedirectToAction method call not running index action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC web development, so the answer may be very simple. I'm creating a very simple MVC web app. I have a POST method that executes when clicking a save button, then my index action should be called but never is.

```
[HttpPost]
  public RedirectToRouteResult SaveClimber(ClimberDto climber)
  {
    //method call that takes climber makes a calculation and saves to SQL dabase
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var viewModel = GetViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
  }
```

Comment: `RedirectToAction` sends an HTTP 302 to the browser with a new URL to visit. What exactly is happening?

Comment: Are both the actions in the same controller?

Comment: Like to reiterate @DarthJam's question. I rarely use RedirectToRouteResult because I don't like the permanent redirect flag. I always use `ActionResult` as the return type on my controller action methods and have never had an issue redirecting to an index page.

Comment: Yes both actions are in the same controller. I essentially have some input boxes and a table that gets updated with a new line after I input data then click the save button. One of the table data columns is a calculated value that gets calculated just before the save occurs. What happens is when I click save, the new line shows up without the calculated amount, and the input boxes retain the inputs added. When I refresh the browser the calculated value is added to the table, and input boxes are cleared. I'm trying to avoid a manual refresh to get the desired result.

Comment: I changed the return type to ActionResult, and this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you put a break point within the Index function to see if it is being called at all?

Also, how are you calling SaveClimber? From your description it sounds like you are making an ajax call (or some other front end call). Getting that from your suggestion of a manual refresh.